# How can I destroy a widget component in ue4 blueprints?

Tags: widget, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I have a question regarding UE4 widget objects in blueprints. I try to spawn new widget objects at runtime and add them to a unit. Then I want to play a simple animation and destroy the created widget afterwards. However I don't know how to destroy a widget component.

If I try to simply remove from parent I get the following warning:

> UWidget::RemoveFromParent() called on '/Engine/Transient.UnrealEdEngine_0:GameInfoInstance_C_0.DamageWidget_C_12' which has no UMG parent (if it was added directly to a native Slate widget via TakeWidget() then it must be removed explicitly rather than via RemoveFromParent())

I also don't want to use the same widget component (and set the new widget as the existing one) because it overwrites the existing widget component and cancels the animation if two widgets are spawned at nearly the same time(which I don't want).

[image]

How can I destroy my created widget component? I also don't want to just hide it because of memory issues.